# Zip files in folder using PHP

Tags: php, yii, zip

I've a folder which contains all the uploaded files and I am storing path of each file in database according to user id. Now I want to read all files of that particular user and want write all that files into a zipped folder.

How can I do it with PHP?

My code:

```
// Getting file path here
$data = $model->findAll('tree_parent_id=:id', array(':id' => (int) $model->id));
foreach ($data as $type) {
  print_r($type->path);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written function to do it, Which i use it in my projects:

```
$file: files arary
$zipnam: what to name your zip file
$dir: where to keep your zipped file
$del: should i delete files from source folder after zipping it?
```

Function:

```
function zipit($file, $zipnam, $dir, $del=TRUE) {
    $filestozip = $file; // FILES ARRAY TO ZIP
    $dir = trim($dir); // DIR NAME TO MOVE THE ZIPPED FILES
    $zipnam = trim($zipnam);

    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $files = $filestozip;
    $zip_name = $zipnam.".zip";
    $fizip = $dir.$zip_name;
    if($zip->open($fizip, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
        foreach ($files as $fl) {
          if(file_exists($fl)){
            $zip->addFromString(basename($fl),  file_get_contents($fl));
            if($del === TRUE) {
                unlink($fl);
            }
          }
        }
        $zip->close();
        return TRUE;
    } else { $zip->close(); return FALSE;}
}
```

Comment: Its creating zip of files but not loading images

Comment: Here is the file array: `Array
(
    [0] => /var/www/app/app/data/p3media/1/Screenshot from 2013-10-11 16:17:53-52a2ef76eae11.png
    [1] => /var/www/app/app/data/p3media/1/Screenshot from 2013-09-26 18:39:31.png
    [2] => /var/www/app/app/data/p3media/1/Screenshot from 2013-11-21 21:01:16.png
    [3] => /var/www/app/app/data/p3media/1/Screenshot from 2013-10-11 16:17:53.png
)`

Comment: What images it should load?

Comment: Given path image like this : `Screenshot from 2013-10-11 16:17:53.png`

Comment: Solved..That was issue of permission.

Answer (score 0):

Yii has a zip [extension.](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ezip/)

```
 $zip = Yii::app()->zip;
 $zip->makeZip('./','./toto.zip'); // make an ZIP archive 
 $zip->extractZip('./toto.zip', './1/'); // extract Zip arc.
```